# Possibility OF doing or TO do something?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: I hesitate to suggest that [*the possibility to use*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+possibility+to+use%2Cthe+possibility+of+using&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20possibility%20to%20use%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20possibility%20of%20using%3B%2Cc0) an infinitive in such constructions is an ungrammatical option only exercised by non-native speakers, but as that NGram shows, it's not at all common (and I don't like it one little bit).

Comment: Yeah, _possibility_ doesn't take an infinitive complement. _Possible_ doesn't either, except for full subject clauses like _(For him) to arrive late is possible_, most likely extraposed as _It's possible (for him) to arrive late_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Sorry, but your claim about "possible" not accepting a to-infinitive is wrong. I'm not sure about "possibility to", but it may be unacceptable in some dialects of English and acceptable in others.

Comment: If in doubt whether after a noun prep + gerund or to-infinitive follows I think you have to check each noun individually. I think "possibility of doing" is the preferred construction.

Answer (score 2):

"**possible to** VP" is allowed when VP is an infinitive verb phrase whose subject can be inferred easily.

Examples from dictionaries (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Collins English Dictionary):

> Is it **possible to** move faster than the speed of light?
>
> Is it **possible to** enter the gallery at this hour?
>
> It is not **possible to** finish in three weeks.

Examples from TheFreeLibrary:

> ... it will be **possible to** have an excellent body of well-trained militia ...
>
> Nor, in general, is it **possible to** secure it again until the whale is fairly captured and a corpse.
>
> ... whether, if he turned John out a second time, as his outraged authority suggested, it was **possible to** avoid a scandal ...
>
> ... for I had often been musing whether it might not be **possible to** get a kid or two, and so raise a breed of tame goats ...

In fact, it is almost always possible to use "possible to" when describing the possibility of doing something, and often it is preferable, since the alternative would be to say something like "There is always a possibility of using ..."...

As for "**possibility to** VP", some prescriptive dictionaries assert that it is not allowed, probably because it was not used in the past, and also I found no instances of this construction in TheFreeLibrary (which are generally older works). But it seems that some modern speakers use it even in formal language. Here are examples from the BBC and other major news publishers:

> From the Iranian perspective, Russian intervention opens up a new **possibility to** challenge the US-dominated world order ...
>
> Foreigners are only allowed residency if they or their spouse have full-time jobs - there is no **possibility to** remain permanently in the Gulf without work ...
>
> The agreement itself does include the **possibility to** reintroduce controls for maximum one month.
>
> ... with boat workers often isolated at sea for months at a time at the mercy of their captain and no **possibility to** communicate with the outside world.

Personally I'll stick to "**possibility of** CP" where CP is the appropriate gerund such as "doing" or "having gone".

Comment: If you have a preposition like of + an ing-form then it is a gerund, and not a participle.

Comment: @rogermue: Right. Sorry I don't know how I slipped up on that one! I'll edit straightaway.

Answer (score -2):

Doing means you are currently doing it right this moment. Or if you say you like doing something it means it's your hobby. If sometimes you say you like to do something it would probably be more likely to be understood as you just want to do it at that specific time.

Using to do we usually means like it's to be done, and it's not happened yet.